# how to make JSON file in below tree format?

Tags: javascript, json

how to make JSON file in below tree format?

```
  root
     child1
        child11
     child2
        child21
        child22
     child3
        child31
```

i want create one sample JSON file which needs to be in above tree format.

Comment: Did you take a look at http://json.org/? There you can find anything you need to know about JSON syntax.

Comment: Yes NaN, i looked on that but i couldn't make it correct format. can you help me this.

Comment: @Moorthi There are *a number* of ways to create such a structure in JSON, none of which is more ‘correct’ than the other. Unless, of course, you need to follow a certain specification *that you didn't mention*. Perhaps if you told us what it is that you're trying to achieve we could help you out.

Comment: It kind of depends on the types of information you want to store too, but [this might give you a head start](http://jsfiddle.net/exnka87v/).

Comment: Thanks for your response Andy..

Comment: Blffen:- Just i wanted to one best sample JSON code of the tree representation.

Comment: @Moorthi Define ‘best’.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like

```
 {
    "child1": ["child11"],
    "child2": ["child21","child22"],
    "child3": ["child31"]
  }
```

depending on the data that the child elements hold, are they objects or are they arrays?